# How to build glibc on or for armv7l architecture with a FLOSS toolchain?

Tags: compilation, glibc, armv7

Problems are

- with git tag `glibc-2.4` from https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git and others `/path/to/source/root/configure` prints `checking sysdep dirs... configure: error: The armv7l is not supported.`
- the glibc-ports project (https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc-ports.git ) no longer seems to be maintained

I'm using software which depends on glibc on an armv7l system, so there has to be a way to build it.

Comment: Why 2.4 ? That is 8 years old.

Comment: Should run on a Synology DSM 5.x system and fulfill dependencies. I didn't know that the version release is so far in the past. I guess it not a good idea to pursue this except for an exercise.

Comment: Anyway, glibc-ports was integrated with glibc just a year or so ago. If you really need to use 2.4 then you just need the matching glibc-ports 2.4 version.